# android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat render error in targetSdkVersion 24 (Android N)

Tags: android, layout, switch-statement, android-appcompat, switchcompat

I am using

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
}
```

for

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 24
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
   minSdkVersion 18
   targetSdkVersion 24
}
```

I have an Activity with a theme

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

and would like to use a layout with switches. I used

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat />
```

earlier (with older SDK versions) and it worked fine. Now however, SwitchCompat switches render wired. Here is what I get for the two different switches in my layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
   android:text="android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat"/>
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
   android:text="Switch" />
```

In OFF

[image: Switches in off position]

and in ON mode

[image: Switches in on position]

Is this a bug in the Android N SDK? Or the appcompat-v7:24.0.0? Od did I miss something?

Answer (score -2):

The problem is `--no-crunch` in combination with `targetSdkVersion 24`. Removing `--no-crunch` solved the issue for me.

I am using Xamarin, so I had `<AndroidResgenExtraArgs>--no-crunch </AndroidResgenExtraArgs>` in my .csproj file. I don't know where is `--no-crunch` specified in native android but I guess it won't be a problem to find id.